# scala.MatchError Message whenever I run Scala Object

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming, twitter4j

The following piece of code is apart of a Twitter Streaming app that I'm using with Spark Streaming.:

```
val Array(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) = args.take(4)
val filters = args.takeRight(args.length - 4)

// Set the system properties so that Twitter4j library used by twitter stream
// can use them to generate OAuth credentials
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)
```

Whenever I go to run the program, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" scala.MatchError: [Ljava.lang.String;@323659f8 (of class [Ljava.lang.String;)
at SparkPopularHashTags$.main(SparkPopularHashTags.scala:18)
at SparkPopularHashTags.main(SparkPopularHashTags.scala)
```

Line 18 is:

```
val Array(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) = args.take(4)
```

I have the Twitter4j.properties file saved in my F:\Software\ItelliJ\Projects\twitterStreamApp\src folder, and it's formatted like so:

```
oauth.consumerKey=***
oauth.consumerSecret=***
oauth.accessToken=***
oauth.accessTokenSecret=***
```

Where the "*"s are my keys without quotations around them (i.e. oauth.consumerKey=h12b31289fh7139fbh138ry)

Can anyone assist me with this please?

```
import org.apache.spark.streaming.{ Seconds, StreamingContext }
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.twitter._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.{ SparkContext, SparkConf }
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel
import org.apache.spark.streaming.flume._
import twitter4j.auth.OAuthAuthorization
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder

object SparkPopularHashTags {
  val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("Spark Streaming - PopularHashTags")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    sc.setLogLevel("WARN")

    val Array(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) = args.take(4)
//    val filters = args.takeRight(args.length - 4)


    args.lift(0).foreach { consumerKey =>
      System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
    }
    args.lift(1).foreach { consumerSecret =>
      System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
    }
    args.lift(2).foreach { accessToken =>
      System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
    }
    args.lift(3).foreach { accessTokenSecret =>
      System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)
    }

    val filters = args.drop(4)
    // Set the system properties so that Twitter4j library used by twitter stream
    // can use them to generate OAuth credentials
//    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
//    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
//    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
//    System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)

    // Set the Spark StreamingContext to create a DStream for every 5 seconds
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(5))

    val stream = TwitterUtils.createStream(ssc, None, filters)

    // Split the stream on space and extract hashtags
    val hashTags = stream.flatMap(status => status.getText.split(" ").filter(_.startsWith("#")))

    // Get the top hashtags over the previous 60 sec window
    val topCounts60 = hashTags.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(60))
      .map { case (topic, count) => (count, topic) }
      .transform(_.sortByKey(false))

    // Get the top hashtags over the previous 10 sec window
    val topCounts10 = hashTags.map((_, 1)).reduceByKeyAndWindow(_ + _, Seconds(10))
      .map { case (topic, count) => (count, topic) }
      .transform(_.sortByKey(false))

    // print tweets in the correct DStream
    stream.print()

    // Print popular hashtags
    topCounts60.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      val topList = rdd.take(10)
      println("\nPopular topics in last 60 seconds (%s total):".format(rdd.count()))
      topList.foreach { case (count, tag) => println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count)) }
    })
    topCounts10.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      val topList = rdd.take(10)
      println("\nPopular topics in last 10 seconds (%s total):".format(rdd.count()))
      topList.foreach { case (count, tag) => println("%s (%s tweets)".format(tag, count)) }
    })

    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks like `args` has fewer than 4 elements, so need to see the code where that is created.

Comment: @Tim I have updated the code

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
val Array(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessTokenSecret) = args.take(4)
```

This will fail if there are fewer than 4 arguments because it can't match the four values on the left hand side.

Instead, you need to test the elements of `args` individually to make sure they are present. For example

```
args.lift(0).foreach { consumerKey =>
  System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerKey", consumerKey)
}
args.lift(1).foreach { consumerSecret =>
  System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.consumerSecret", consumerSecret)
}
args.lift(2).foreach { accessToken =>
  System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessToken", accessToken)
}
args.lift(3).foreach { accessTokenSecret =>
  System.setProperty("twitter4j.oauth.accessTokenSecret", accessTokenSecret)
}

val filters = args.drop(4)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I'm new to Scala. How would I test this. I added the "args.lift..." to the setProperty lines, commented out the val filters I created and added yours, but I still get the same MatchError.

Comment: I've also updated my code to the entire object and with the changes I ran.

Comment: You left in the line that was causing the error. I've update the question to explain why it fails. Note that this code will still not work if you actually need all four values, so the problem might be the way this program is being run.

Comment: Thank you so much Tim. I realized what the issue was. I'm using IntelliJ, and my program was expecting the args to come from the command line. I just needed to add command line arguments to the project, and I was able to move past the issue. 

Your comment really helped me figure out where the issue was coming from.

Answer (score 0):

This should happen only when your not setting your Program arguments or setting insufficient no. of arguments i.e. less than 4